# Can one use self-hypnosis or subliminal messages to wipe out selected memories from my brain (i.e. selective permanent amnesia)?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, hypnosis, ptsd, amnesia

Is it possible to use self-hypnosis or subliminal messages to completely forget certain memories from one's brain, to cure from mental disorders as PTSD, if such memories are troubling one's life?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is post traumatic stress disorder preventable?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16781/is-post-traumatic-stress-disorder-preventable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Is it possible to erase problematic memories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/10079/7001) or [Is is possible to "delete" a memory permanently?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/21319/7001)